# Proving the kernel of a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to show that $\ker(\varphi)=<2\pi>$ where $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \to \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ by $\varphi(x)=\begin{bmatrix} \cos(x) & \sin(x) \\ -\sin(x) & \cos(x) \end{bmatrix}$.  I was originally trying to use containment in both directions, but would an iff chain work as well?  Here is my attempt:

By the uniqueness of the identity, noting that the identity of SL$_2(\mathbb{R})=$I$_2$.  Therefore:

$G=\ker(\varphi) \iff \cos(g)=1 \text{ and } \sin(g)=0, \forall g\in G \\
\sin(g)=0 \text{ and } \cos(g)=1 \iff g=k2\pi \;, k\in \mathbb{Z} \;, \forall g\in G \\
\text{every } g\in G = k2\pi \iff G=<2\pi>$.

Does this work or do I need to go back to $G\subseteq \ker(\varphi)$ and $\ker(\varphi) \subseteq G$?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach works just fine, so long as you can justify/have justified each "iff" in the chain. It could be better, though. Instead of "$G=\ker(\varphi),$" I would say "$g\in\ker(\varphi).$" That lets you leave out the "$\forall g\in G$" parts of the chain along the way, and your new (simpler) chain becomes: $$\begin{align}g\in\ker(\varphi) &\Longleftrightarrow \cos(g)=1\text{ and }\sin(g)=0\\ &\Longleftrightarrow \exists k\in\Bbb Z\:(g=k2\pi)\\ &\Longleftrightarrow \exists g\in\langle2\pi\rangle\end{align}$$

I made a few other changes along the way, too, which you should note. If you aren't sure why I made them, just ask.

Comment: Thanks! Of course your's looks must cleaner, and I believe I understand all of the changes you made.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I guess I should ask (though I feel like this was implied in the answer) do you feel like every step in the chain is justified?

Comment: Justifiable, yes. I haven't seen your work, nor have I seen the results you have to work with, so I can't really say if each step in the chain is justified.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you showed that if $\cos(g)=1$ and $\sin(g)=0$, then $g=2k\pi,\;k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, every $g\in\text{Ker}(\varphi)$ will also be such that $g\in<2\pi>:=\{2k\pi\,|\,k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\subset\mathbb{R}$, i.e, $\text{Ker}(\varphi)\subset<2\pi>$.

Obviously, if $g\in<2\pi>$ (because every integer multiple of $2\pi$ is such that its $\cos$ is one and its $\sin$ is zero), then $g\in\text{Ker}(\varphi)$, i.e, $<2\pi>\subset\text{Ker}(\varphi)$.

The two set inclusions above leads to the required equality. What you did in your proof was simply to show the two paragraphs above "simultaneous", with the iff's. Nevertheless, it is totally right.